# react-router 2.8 Link to add path instead of replace

Tags: hyperlink, pagination, react-router

I am try to make pagination with react-router and redux. 
To simplify the situation, I removed my paginator and left only News component.
I have the same problem. When I push button Route adds to path. And path looks like 'http://localhost:3000/news/page/news/page/news/page/4'.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'
  
export default class News extends Component {
  render() {
    let nextPage = + (this.props.params.page || 1);
    return(
    <div>
    <h1>I am on {nextPage}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><Link to='news/page/2'>Page2</Link></li>
      <li><Link to='news/page/3'>Page3</Link></li>
      <li><Link to='news/page/4'>Page4</Link></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  )
    }}
```

```js
export const routes = (
  <div>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      {/*}<IndexRedirect to='list' />*/}
      <Route path='/news(/page/:page)' component={News}/>    
      <Route path='/admin' component={Admin}  onEnter={Admin.onEnter}/>
      <Route path='products' component={Products}/>
      <Route path='contacts' component={Contacts}/>
      <Route path='about' component={About} />
      <Route path='login' component={LoginPage} />
      <Route path='orders' component= {Orders}/>
      <Route path='signup' component={SignupPage}/>
      <Route path='validateEmail' component= {requireIdentification(ValidateEmail)}/>
      <Route path='/verifyEmail/:token' component={CheckEmail}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 4):

The decision is

```js
<li><Link to='/news/page/2'>Page2</Link></li>
```

instead of

```js
<li><Link to='news/page/2'>Page2</Link></li>
```